# How to work with Sql Server and Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've been at this for many, many hours and I've run into nothing but roadblocks.  All I want to do is to start a project in Visual C# 2010 that connects to a SQL database.  I've always worked with Access databases and I want to learn how to with SQL Server.  Who would have thought it would be this much trouble.

In my programs files (on my home computer) I have Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Server Compact Edition. Under Sql server there is a folder `80`, `90`, `100`, `110`, `MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS`. In the Server compact Edition folder there is `v3.5` & `v4.0`. I have MS SQL Server Managment Studio (installed & reinstalled 2 times to finally work) and when I open it it says `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I Downloaded the `Adventuresworks` database and finally got it to connect in management studio, but when i try to connect in Visual studio (add new data source) I get errors, wrong version, etc. So I now try connecting using connection string, but I don't know which database to connect to.. nor how to write it. There are multiple databases in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA` from my adventure works install.

I also read that with Windows Vista there is a permissions issue (only Administrator can install and access databases).

How do I resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: You may want to open your `SQL Server Management` window. All the instances are there.

Comment: BTW, if you have some trouble with `Add new DataSource` wizard, why don't you post the screen shot of the window reporting exceptions and errors?

Comment: See this page for a nice list http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587

Comment: Are you trying to open AdventureWorks file straight visual studio? SQL isn't like access that you open the file, but you connect to the SQLServer and from there you use the server to do your work. When you use compact edition you can use the attachment of the file but, first you need to detach AdventureWorks from the sqlserver. I suggest you to follow @KingKing suggestion for start, and allow me to welcome to the SQLSERVER world, which in my opinion is much more rewarding than Access

Comment: You might want this one which is an earlier version - http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/478218

Comment: What do you mean "Are you trying to open AdventureWorks file straight visual studio?"  I couldn't add new data source, so now I'm trying it using a connection string.  Are you saying I have to add new data source then do a connection string?  I'm downloading that earlier version of Adventureworks right now.

Comment: 'Compact edition' is for WinCE - Smartphones. You want to attach the AdventureWorks database to SQL Server Express.  The default installation SQL name is 'localhost\SQLExpress'.  If you gave it some other name bring up task manager and look at services.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that getting started with SQL Server can be quite maddening. That said, your connection strings are not really based on folder locations on your machine. Instead, when connecting to SQL Server on your own computer, the server name is usually "localhost" then possibly followed by an instance name--for example localhost\sqlexpress. You can also use your computer name in place of "localhost." A full connection string would look like:

Data Source=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI

In code, you test this by doing something like

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    cn.Open();
    cn.Close();
}
```

This will essentially test a connection.

The easiest way to find servers you can connect to is to use the Browse for Servers dialog when connecting in SSMS (but this depends on the SQL Browse service running).

[image]

here you can see I have two instances that are named after my computer. I can use either the name "adam-laptop" or "localhost" to form

Data Source=adam-laptop;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI

or

Data Source=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI

or

Data Source=localhost\sql2012;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI

or

Data Source=adam-laptop\sql2012;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI

Comment: btw my answer did not address connecting to SQL Server Compact edition.... I don't do that very much....

Comment: Where is this Browse for server dialog?

Comment: it's on the Connect dialog in SQL Server Management Studio--within the Server Name dropdown--there's a <browse for more> item in the server list